# Casperjs click button not working

Tags: web-scraping, casperjs

I'm able to fill the inputs in this website yet I can't click the submit button, already tried with many methods. If you could be so kind to test the solution you propose, please. Thanks

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("https://alsea.interfactura.com/RegistroDocumento.aspx?opc=Starbucks");
casper.then(function() {
    casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda', '12345');
    casper.click('input[type="submit"][id="ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_btnContinue"]');
    casper.capture("test.png");
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a bit around, i got a solution with a static wait in it. You can replace it with a waitForSelector():

```
    var casper = require('casper').create();

    casper.start("https://alsea.interfactura.com/RegistroDocumento.aspx?opc=Starbucks");

    casper.then(function() {
      casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtRFC', 'VSC162114Q6A');
      casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTicket', '208456752');
      casper.sendKeys('#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtTienda', '38445');
      // set via jQuery because of the date format
      casper.evaluate(function() {
        $("#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_txtDate").val('01/01/2017');
      });
    });
    casper.then(function() {
      casper.capture("test1.png");
    });
    casper.then(function() {
      casper.evaluate(function() {
        $("#ctl00_Main_RegistroClienteTicket1_btnContinue").click();
      });
    });
    // You have to wait for dynamic loaded stuff here
    casper.wait(5000);

    casper.then(function() {
      casper.capture("test2.png");
    });
    casper.run();
```

Thanks for the data. It makes the research easier (i changed it again if you want to delete your comment again). ;)

Comment: You are awesome dasmelch, it works great! If there's any chance we can work together please let me know